# Django2.1- error- everything was working fine but it started giving {% ur 'name' %}l error

Tags: django, python-3.x

[image][image]

everything was working fine but it started giving {% ur 'name' %}l error, when i delete this works fine!Using to django-2.1, jinja2, python-3.6

Comment: In your url's py, you most probably forgot the specify the kwarg name as `name='index'` and wrote `parh(r'whatever', 'index')` instead.

If not, you probably should post your urls.py

Comment: added the url.py- https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMB2q.png

Comment: Can you also include the other urls?

Comment: https://github.com/tsuryaa/hollobers/tree/master/hollober

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts', views.accounts,name='accounts'),
    path('friends',views.friends,name='friends'),
    path('about',views.about,name='about'),
    path('photo',views.photo,name='photo'),
    path('video',views.video,name='video'),
    path('favpage',views.favpage,name='favpage'),
    path('accountsetting', views.accountsetting, name='accountsetting'),
    path('personalinfo', views.personalinfo, name='personalinfo'),
    path('favpagecreate', views.favpagecreate, name='favpagecreate'),
    path('friendgroup', views.friendgroup,name='friendgroup'),
    path('Hobbies', views.Hobbies, name='Hobbies'),
    path('notification', views.notification,'notification'), # this one
    path('Education', views.Education, name='Education'),
    path('changepass', views.changepass, name='changepass'),
    path('chatmessage', views.chatmessage, name='chatmessage'),
    path('friendrequest', views.friendrequest, name='friendrequest'),
]
```

As I mentioned in the comment, you are missing the `name=` part, so it takes it as `kwargs` value which is used to put keyword arguments to view functions. If you fix that part, the error should go away.